# Function returns 1 even when there's not matching record

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have the following function on a package. When running that the function against non-matching record, the result is always 1.

*This is how I run the function and see output in DBMS Output window*

```
set serveroutpuut on;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line (BP$BUSINESSPARNTNER_CODE.Check_rec('44887'));
end;
```

*This is the function that's responsible for query and counting the records*

```
   FUNCTION Check_rec(PartnerNumber IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS v_count NUMBER;
   BEGIN
        select count(PartnerNumber) into v_count from BusinessPartner where PartnerNumber = PartnerNumber and code is not null;
        RETURN v_count;
   END;
```

*I have tried running with the hard-coded value and it works*

```
FUNCTION Check_rec(PartnerNumber IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS v_count NUMBER;
       BEGIN
            select count(PartnerNumber) into v_count from BusinessPartner where PartnerNumber = '44887' and code is not null;
            RETURN v_count;
       END;
```

Comment: `where PartnerNumber = PartnerNumber` is always true. Either rename your parameter as Tim Biegeleisen suggested, or else specify it explicitly using `where PartnerNumber = check_rec.PartnerNumber`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try changing the name of your `IN` parameter so that it does not conflict with column names:

```
FUNCTION Check_rec(pn IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(PartnerNumber) INTO v_count
    FROM BusinessPartner
    WHERE PartnerNumber = pn AND code IS NOT NULL;
    RETURN v_count;
END;
```

I don't know the rules which Oracle would use to resolve your current situation, but even if it could be made to work, it would probably be best to just avoid it.